# JAVA - Dividing int array into n sets with minimum difference

Tags: arrays, recursion, integer, partitioning, minimum

So I am trying to figure out an algorithm for a program that would use recursion for taking an int array of x numbers and dividing it into n sets. These numbers can be both positive and negative. The sets need to have the smallest difference possible between them.

For example if you gave the program the int array [1, 2, 3, 4] and tell it to divide into 3 groups, then it would divide it into [1, 3] [2] and [4] where the difference between the sets is 2. 
Another example is if you gave the array [6, 6, 6, 10, 10] and tell it to divide into 2 groups, then it would divide it into [10, 10] and [6, 6, 6] where the difference between the sets is 2.

We can assume the array is sorted into ascending order (with smallest at the left and largest at the right) since sorting it would be a simple sort statement. Any ideas?

EDIT: I understand that I am dealing with a Partition problem and I have tried the Greedy Algorithm where you go from largest to smallest numbers and put them in the group with the lowest sum but it wouldn't work for the second example I gave above so I am looking for a more reliable algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The partition problem in the more general case (`k` sets) is known as the [minimum makespan problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling). This problem is NP-complete for `k > 2`. An exact algorithm, the [Graham list scheduling algorithm](http://www.risc.jku.at/education/courses/ws96/intropar/sched/index_5.html), is known for `k = 2` and `k = 3`. For larger sizes, there are a [number of polynomial-time approximation algorithms](http://books.google.com/books?id=i3S9_GnHZwYC&lpg=PA455&ots=nCmnt7IsNs&dq=graham%20list%20scheduling&pg=PA455#v=onepage&q=graham%20list%20scheduling&f=false) if you don't implement an NP-complete solution.